Need help identifying japanese chisels
I'm hoping someone could help me identify the maker or provide some more info on the chisels I purchased.
The box roughly translates to:

Handmade suminagashi


Koresaku, the third generation of the human-linked Akaman


hand-made Sumimoto group

AFAIK this seems to be saying it's made by a company called Sumimoto but based on some googling that company isn't known for making tools.
Would appreciate any help!




Based on these ebay postings: one and two, where the box lid looks identical and contain 10 chisels, I believe the company is Sukemasa or Sukemasa Suminagashi (though I believe suminagashi refers to the damascus look).
This site seems to sell them and contains more info about them (slightly different variant):

Craftsman/職人: Unknown・不明
Place/地域: Echigo Yoita・越後与板打刃物
Steel/鋼: White steel・白紙鋼
Jigane/地金: Iron Laminated material・積層材
Blade width/刃幅:
5mm/48mm/42mm/36mm/30mm/24mm
21mm/18mm/15mm/12mm/9mm/6mm/4.5mm/3mm/2mm
Full length/全長: about 220mm
Blade angle/刃角: about 24 °


That appears to be it thank you! I can't seem to find much info on what or where Sukemasa exactly is so maybe will need to do some digging.
